# Assign Javascript value to a java String in a jsp

Tags: javascript, java, string, jsp

I am using JavaScript in my project. I need a way to save a JavaScript value to a java String in a jsp. I do not want to make a Ajax call as there are lot of complexities. I tried a lot but is there a way to set javaScript value to a string in a jsp?

Note: I do not want AJAX calls as mentioned. I just want to know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: You just can't directly set JSP string from JavaScript

Comment: @Satpal are there any alternatives to ajax call to pass the data to backend??

Comment: You need to submit it either by using AJAX or input fields no other way